# Binary or unsupported text Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, text, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, binary

When I trying to crawling at Korean website but there was error message as below.

"This file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding."

and when I open in file editor, it shows like this.

MZ�uH����������������������

Can you please help me with this?
Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen 

response = urlopen('https://datalab.naver.com/keyword/realtimeList.naver? 
where=main')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
for anchor in soup.select("span.item_title"):
    print(anchor)
```

Comment: show the command you used to get the file. Files beginning with `MZ` are most likely windows executable files.

Comment: What's the filename extension?

Comment: that's for python, extension is py.

Comment: Do you have tried to open it in a notebook? what it is like?

Comment: It does not look like a python file, although the filename extension is 'py'. I tried to rename a '.exe' file to '.py' file, the vscode prompt the same information as you provided. When I force to open it, it just looks like what you provide, it starts with MZ. So, I agree with rioV8, it more looks like an executable file rather than a python file, although the filename extension is py.

Answer (score 0):

[image: MarketPlace]

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it may be something to look into. VS code has a Marketplace where you can get extensions for free